# Google Map API marker update from JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I would like to ask you a solution for this problem.
I have a JS with a variable inside that is updated overtime by a JAVA application (i.e. JAVA writer into a thread), after that I take the coordinates from that variable and I create a new object Marker for my google maps. **The problem is that the marker does not changes position, it changes only if I refresh the whole page (I dont want to do this).**

Here's the code to be more clear. 
The inputData.js where the variable is written by the java application

```
var newMarker = {'latitude':38.25705300000004,'longitude': 140.83760400000006};
```

my html page used to display the map

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Simple markers</title>
        <style>
            html, body, #map-canvas {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY">
        </script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="inputData.js"></script>
        <script>
                    var map;
                    var sendai = new google.maps.LatLng(38.259535, 140.846816);
                    var lastPosition;
                    var image = 'images/circle-16.png';

                    function initialize() {
                        var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 12,
                            center: sendai,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
                    }

                    setInterval(refreshData, 2000);

                    function refreshData() {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: image,
                            draggable: false
                        });
                        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(newMarker.latitude, newMarker.longitude));
                        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(newMarker.latitude, newMarker.longitude));
                        map.setZoom(18);
                    }

                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I open my page like this everything work but when I change the script "inputData.js" the marker does not changes position.
The method setCenter on the other hand seems to work properly.

Help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to reload the updated script to get the updated position:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 18,
          center: sendai,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP},
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
                                  mapOptions),
        //we will store the LatLng here
        pos = new google.maps.MVCObject(),
        //use a single marker with updated position
        marker  = new google.maps.Marker();

    //set the latLng of the MVCObject
    pos.set('latLng',new google.maps.LatLng(newMarker.latitude,
                                            newMarker.longitude));
    //bind the markers position to the latLng of the MVCObject
    marker.bindTo('position',pos,'latLng');

    marker.setMap(map);

    setInterval(function(){
          //the currently loaded script
      var script=document.querySelector('script[src^="inputData.js"]'),
          //the updated script
          update=document.createElement('script');
          //load-handler for the updated script
          google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(update,'load',function(){
            pos.set('latLng',new google.maps.LatLng(newMarker.latitude,
                                                    newMarker.longitude));
            map.setCenter(pos.get('latLng'));
            map.setZoom(18);
          });
          //replace current script with updated script 
          script.parentNode.replaceChild(update,script);
          //load update
          update.src='inputData.js?'+new Date().getTime();
    },2000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create new instance of marker every time. Update your code with this and try:

```
var map;
var sendai = new google.maps.LatLng(38.259535, 140.846816);
var lastPosition;
var image = 'images/circle-16.png';

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: sendai,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

var marker;
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      draggable: false
});
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(newMarker.latitude, newMarker.longitude));
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(newMarker.latitude, newMarker.longitude));
map.setZoom(18);

setInterval(refreshData, 2000);
function refreshData() {
     marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(newMarker.latitude, newMarker.longitude));
     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(newMarker.latitude, newMarker.longitude));
     map.setZoom(18);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thank you but your code give me an error on the variable map. Also if I fix it the problem is the same, in order to update the marker position I have to update the whole page.

Comment: Alright, now I get your point, so the problem is; you are updating a file via JAVA but actually this will never update the variables in the browser on run-time because whenever we load a page browser loads the file and interprets the JavaScript and create variables in memory until the window is closed or refreshed the same process then repeats. 
In Dr.Molle answer above he is re-loading the js file on time interval to fix this.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry problably I did not explain my problem clearly enough. Thank you btw.